# Why can't i add a textview above another textview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I wanted to add a TextView above another TextView like in this image:[image]

This is the code that i'm using currently but i don't have the TextView that would be title with the code that i have. I only have the description. I tried adding a RelativeLayout and another TextView but the TextView disappeared. How can i make this without breaking my code?Thanks

My xml layout for my TextView:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textRight"
            style="@style/ProductList"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

The ProductList style:

```
    <style name="ProductList">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/look_slider_product_price_margin</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: I suggest you take some time to study this guide on android layouts. It covers the basics which will help you to resolve the problem quickly: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout

Answer (score 0):

Set textviews as transparent with
android:background="#07000000"

The draw one over the other and it will be visible.

Comment: I tried that but the image is next to one another and not one above another

Comment: Could you give the complete XML code. Is the root layout the constraint layout?